# /testfor command not working (13w36b)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm working on this new Minecraft project and it involves a lot of command blocks and dummy variables. For some reason, this one does not want to work and I do not understand why. In the image, you can clearly see I have the required points for this variable check and the variable check does not output any signal at all.

Is the syntax an issue or what? I'm eager to know why I am incorrect here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your question? like are you asking what is the problem with your commands/code? I'm confused.

Comment: @Scootaloo Look at the "Previous Output" in the screenshot: this command looks fine, yet is resulting in "Unknown command". That's weird.

Comment: I get "That player cannot be found" when running this. (Note I do not have this variable in the scoreboard.) Do you have the *latest* 13w36b? It was hotfixed twice, and that may have made this behave differently?

Comment: Have you also checked the scoreboard doesn't have a typo?

Comment: To answer in order:

1)The question is why is this getting an Unknown command error.
2)I'm running 13w36 probably the original, I'll reupdate and test again.
3)Scoreboard contains no typo. You can see the objective name on the sidebar.

Comment: After re-updating and testing, I continue to get the same error @SevenSidedDie.

Comment: I would suggest posting all of the commands you used to set everything up.  Add it right to the question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to not be your command, but your clock.

With a comparator clock the redstone dust it is directly feeding to will alternate between 15 and 2 power, and the next dust between 14 and 1. You need to go one dust further out to have a dust which will actually turn fully off and on.

Comment: Alternatively, you can reduce the input power of the comparator by moving the redstone block further away. Note that moving it only by one will still put signal strength 15 into the comparator.

Answer (score -3):

Don't put / before your command on a command block

Comment: Commands work just fine with and without slashes. Tested previously in 13w36b and retested just now in 13w39b.

Answer (score -4):

Try **testfor @p[score_Lobby2UpperADoor,min=1]**

Comment: Why should he try this?  Why will this fix it?

Comment: No, this is incorrect syntax. It's a horrible answer, and Shockwave's command is right, he's just not properly powering the block.